How to clear all Laravel locks when using the redis cache driver?
I am using the redis cache in Laravel. I have a process that acquires a lock:
Cache::lock('myKey')->get()
That process aborted before releasing the lock.
I have tried running php artisan cache:clear to release the lock by clearing the entire cache but this does not work.
If I rerun Cache::lock('myKey')->get() it returns false because it is still locked.
Also, running Cache::lock('myKey')->release() does not work because only the process that created it can clear the lock. I could run Cache::lock('myKey')->forceRelease() to release a lock without respecting its process owner. But I actually have a lot of locks to release.
How to release all locks? Why doesn't php artisan cache:clear work?

Because of the way redis works and how Laravel namespaces redis locks running php artisan cache:clear or Cache::flush() will not release the locks.
To release all locks you should run redis-cli then type FLUSHALL. Then type exit to leave the redis cli.
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> FLUSHALL
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> exit


If you don't want to use redis-cli Laravel provides a Redis facade that allows you to pass raw commands directly to redis.
